# How to set a random color on C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I wanna set a random color from a Canvas but i dont know how

I tried

```
Random r = new Random();
Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb((byte)r.Next(1, 255), 
                  (byte)r.Next(1, 255), (byte)r.Next(1, 233)));
```

Comment: Hi. Please provide more context on what the issue is. Why is the above not working for you? Also, add more code to illustrate the issue. Right now, there's not much to go with. That code kind of looks like it should work and do what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options. One of them:
Give a name to the Canvas:

```
<Canvas x:Name="myCanvas"/>
```

in your code behind assign the color:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Random r = new Random();
    Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb((byte)r.Next(1, 255), 
                    (byte)r.Next(1, 255), (byte)r.Next(1, 233)));
    myCanvas.Background = brush;
}
```

Another way is to take the brush from resources:

```
<Canvas Background="{DynamicResource RandomBrush}" />
```

code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Random r = new Random();
    Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb((byte)r.Next(1, 255), 
                    (byte)r.Next(1, 255), (byte)r.Next(1, 233)));
    this.Resources.Add("RandomBrush",brush);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, appreciate it.